# How to use Spark Riak connector with pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, riak

I'm following the instructions at https://github.com/basho/spark-riak-connector, running Spark 2.0.2-hadoop2.7.

tried -

1) `pyspark --repositories https://dl.bintray.com/basho/data-platform --packages com.basho.riak:spark-riak-connector_2.11:1.6.0`

2) `pyspark --driver-class-path /path/to/spark-riak-connector_2.11-1.6.0-uber.jar`

3) adding `spark.driver.extraClassPath        /path/to/jars/*` to the master's spark-default.conf

4) trying older versions of the connector (1.5.0 and 1.5.1)

I can verify in the master's web ui, in pyspark's app environment that the riak jars are loaded. I also doubled check that spark's scala version is 2.11.

but.. no matter what I do, I don't have the `pyspark_riak` import

```
>>> import pyspark_riak
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyspark_riak
```

how do I fix that ?

when trying option #1, the jars are being loaded and I get this report which looks just fine:

```
:: modules in use:
    com.basho.riak#riak-client;2.0.7 from central in [default]
    com.basho.riak#spark-riak-connector_2.11;1.6.0 from central in [default]
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.8.0 from central in [default]
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.8.0 from central in [default]
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.8.0 from central in [default]
    com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype#jackson-datatype-joda;2.4.4 from central in [default]
    com.fasterxml.jackson.module#jackson-module-scala_2.11;2.4.4 from central in [default]
    com.google.guava#guava;14.0.1 from central in [default]
    joda-time#joda-time;2.2 from central in [default]
    org.erlang.otp#jinterface;1.6.1 from central in [default]
    org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.2 from central in [default]
    :: evicted modules:
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.4.4 by [com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.8.0] in [default]
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.4.4 by [com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.8.0] in [default]
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.4.4 by [com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.8.0] in [default]
    com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.4.0 by [com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.8.0] in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   15  |   11  |   11  |   4   ||   11  |   11  |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

also if I print `sys.path` I can see `/tmp/spark-b2396e0a-f329-4066-b3b1-4e8c21944a66/userFiles-7e423d94-5aa2-4fe4-935a-e06ab2d423ae/com.basho.riak_spark-riak-connector_2.11-1.6.0.jar` (which I verified to exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spark-riak-connector from the repository comes without pyspark support. But you can build it yourself and attach to pyspark:

```
git clone https://github.com/basho/spark-riak-connector.git
cd spark-riak-connector/
python connector/python/setup.py bdist_egg # creates egg file inside connector/python/dist/
```

Then add newly created egg to the python path:

```
pyspark --repositories https://dl.bintray.com/basho/data-platform --packages com.basho.riak:spark-riak-connector_2.11:1.6.0
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('connector/python/dist/pyspark_riak-1.0.0-py2.7.egg')
>>> import pyspark_riak
>>>
```

But be careful using spark-riak-connector with spark 2.0.2 - I see the newest package version is tested with spark 1.6.2 and API may not work as expected.